Creating std::tuple by calling getter methods of a class
In a legacy environment we have lists of objects which are to be sorted according to the values of some members in a various ways.
One idea to go modern c++ 20 is to map an object to std::tuple and sort the tuples. I come up with something like:
template <typename U, typename... Args>
auto createTuple(U obj, Args ...methods)
{
    return std::make_tuple((obj.*methods)() ...);
}

which is called as:
Agg agg{2, 2, 3, 3, {8, 100}};

auto tuple = createTuple<Agg>(agg, &Agg::deliver_j, &Agg::deliver_k);

The deliver methods are part of Agg anyway. So is there a way to get something like:
auto tuple = createTuple<Agg>(agg, deliver_j, deliver_k);

Only types with deliver_j or deliver_k methods should match expansion.
or even this:
auto tuple = createTuple<Agg>(agg, j, k);

The template would take j and somehow add deliver_ to the identifier. (could be done by Macros)
I have an godbold here
That code is here:
#include <variant>
#include <tuple>
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
    
template<std::size_t I, class... Ts>
void doPrintTuple(const std::tuple<Ts...>& tuples) {
    if constexpr (I == sizeof...(Ts)) {
        std::cout << ')';
    }
    else {
        std::cout << std::get<I>(tuples);
        if constexpr (I + 1 != sizeof...(Ts)) {
            std::cout << ", ";
        }
        doPrintTuple<I + 1>(tuples);
    }
}

template<class... Ts>
void printTuple(const std::tuple<Ts...>& tuples) {
    std::cout << '(';
    doPrintTuple<0>(tuples);
}

template <typename U, typename... Args>
auto createTuple(U obj, Args ...methods)
{
    return std::make_tuple((obj.*methods)() ...);
}

struct Something 
{
    int s{};
    int x{};
    int const& deliver_s() const { return s; }
    int const& deliver_x() const { return x; }
};

struct Agg
{
    int i{};
    int j{};
    int k{};
    int l{};
    Something smth{};

    int const& deliver_i() const { return i; }
    int const& deliver_j() const { return j; }
    int const& deliver_k() const { return k; }
    int const& deliver_l() const { return l; }
    Something const& deliver_smth() const { return smth; }
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Agg &g) { 
  return os << g.i << ", " << g.j << ", " << g.k << ", " << g.l << ", {" << g.smth.s << ", " << g.smth.x << "}" << std::endl; 
}

int main()
{

    Agg agg{2, 2, 3, 3, {8, 100}};

    auto tuple = createTuple<Agg>(agg, &Agg::deliver_j, &Agg::deliver_k);

    printTuple(tuple);

}


Note that we can't pass member functions as arguments like we can pass normal function. For example, createTuple<Agg>(agg, deliver_j, deliver_k) wouldn't be valid because deliver_j and deliver_k are member functions which don't decay and the correct syntax to pass them as pointer would be &Classname::deliver_j as you've used in some example of your code.

"is there a way to get something like..." Short answer is no. Member function pointers are not actually pointers. They have special syntax and special rules which are very different from normal pointers. Are pointers to non-static member function "formally" not considered pointers

You don't need to have getters, given auto get_i = &Agg::i; then agg.*get_i is the same as agg.i

It would have to be a macro, because there's now way that i, j can be identified as meaning &Agg::i, &Agg::j, and not any other thing named i or j

But, rather than all this mess, why not std::make_tuple(agg.i, agg.j)? (or perhaps std::tie)

Avoid using macros at all cost. There's a reason why c++ doesn't allow this((agg, deliver_j, deliver_k)).

With MACRO, up to hard-coded limit, you might do createTuple(Agg, agg, j, k), but lambda would be better IMO: const auto proj_ij = [](const Agg& agg){ return std::tie(agg.i, agg.j) ;};.

Thank you very much for the comments. So it is not possible. I tried to get an argument pack declaration as
template <typename U, typename... Args>
auto createTuple0(U obj, Args (U::*...methods)())
{
return std::make_tuple((obj.*methods)() ...);
} which looked like it would do. But there was no way pass the arguments.


is there a way to get something like createTuple<Agg>(agg, deliver_j, deliver_k)

No, because member function pointers are very different from ordinary pointers. They have special syntax for taking their address and unlike ordinary function they also don't implicitly decay to pointer.
Although it is possible to achieve what you want with macros, I wouldn't call that a modern c++ solution.
